# In CNTK python, is there a debug interface to output shape of function parameters

Tags: cntk

The following python code returns an error: *The shape of input operands for the CosDistance operation should have at most one axis.*

> cosine_distance(query_output, document_output)

I would like to debug the parameter shapes. Is there debug interface to output the shape of query_output and document_output?

Answer (score 3):

For a “debug” interface in python you can `import pdb` and then right at the point you want to break into the debugger insert the line:

pdb.set_trace()

from there you can do something like `query_output.shape` and it will show you the shape.

Answer (score 0):

You can just print the shape out via shape attribute of the input variable.